# Request Times out before loading, is there any way to speed up this process of the MySql query?

Tags: mysql, indexing, query-optimization

So, I have tried to combine two tables, one table with over 300,000 rows and another one with about 35,000 rows.

When trying to complete this query, it simply times out when I use "LEFT OUTER JOIN" in order to get all the data from the left hand table and what is in both.

I have also tried with "Explain" and I see that when it queries the other database, it does not use any of the indexes I created for it, rather, it queries the entire table

```sql
SELECT
username as e,
MAX(country) as country, #this is kinda a hacky way to avoid grouping
COALESCE(SUM(a.clicks),0) as clicks,
COALESCE((SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Finance WHERE username=e),0) + COALESCE(SUM(a.registrations),0) as reg,
COALESCE((SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Finance WHERE deposits > 0 AND username=e),0) + COALESCE(SUM(a.ftds),0) as ftds,
COALESCE((SELECT SUM(deposits) FROM Finance WHERE username=e),0) + COALESCE(SUM(a.deposits),0) as deposits,
 COALESCE((SELECT SUM(netcash) FROM Finance WHERE username=e),0) + COALESCE(SUM(a.netrevenue),0) as netcash,
COALESCE(SUM(a.commission),0) as commission
fROM Finance p
LEFT OUTER JOIN xmldata.AllResults a ON SUBSTRING_INDEX(site, "-", 1) = username
GROUP BY username
LIMIT 10000
```

Here is the "Explain":

```sql
+----+--------------------+-----------------+------------+-------+-------------------------------+-------------------------------+---------+------+--------+----------+----------------------------------------------------+
| id | select_type        | table           | partitions | type  | possible_keys                 | key                           | key_len | ref  | rows   | filtered | Extra                                              |
+----+--------------------+-----------------+------------+-------+-------------------------------+-------------------------------+---------+------+--------+----------+----------------------------------------------------+
|  1 | PRIMARY            | p               | NULL       | index | playerdbfinance_email_country | playerdbfinance_email_country | 388     | NULL | 377031 |   100.00 | Using index; Using temporary; Using filesort       |
|  1 | PRIMARY            | a               | NULL       | ALL   | NULL                          | NULL                          | NULL    | NULL |  32765 |   100.00 | Using where; Using join buffer (Block Nested Loop) |
|  5 | DEPENDENT SUBQUERY | PlayerDBFinance | NULL       | ref   | playerdbfinance_email_country | playerdbfinance_email_country | 194     | func |      2 |   100.00 | NULL                                               |
|  4 | DEPENDENT SUBQUERY | PlayerDBFinance | NULL       | ref   | playerdbfinance_email_country | playerdbfinance_email_country | 194     | func |      2 |   100.00 | NULL                                               |
|  3 | DEPENDENT SUBQUERY | PlayerDBFinance | NULL       | ref   | playerdbfinance_email_country | playerdbfinance_email_country | 194     | func |      2 |    33.33 | Using where                                        |
|  2 | DEPENDENT SUBQUERY | PlayerDBFinance | NULL       | ref   | playerdbfinance_email_country | playerdbfinance_email_country | 194     | func |      2 |   100.00 | Using index                                        |
+----+--------------------+-----------------+------------+-------+-------------------------------+-------------------------------+---------+------+--------+----------+----------------------------------------------------+
```

Answer (score 1):

Four correlated subqueries is a performance problem.  The *cross join* between p and a is another big problem.

Fix that by having a derived table that computes, with `GROUP BY` all the subqueries.  Then `JOIN finance USING(username)` to finish the task.

The use of `a` need be done only once.

```
SELECT f.username, x.reg, ...
    FROM ( SELECT COALESCE(SUM(a.registrations),0) AS reg, ... ) AS a
    JOIN ( SELECT
                  COALESCE ... AS reg,
                  COALESCE ...
                  COALESCE ...
                  COALESCE ...
              FROM finance
              GROUP BY username ) AS x
    JOIN finance AS f USING(username)
```

Ugh!  It gets worse

```
SUBSTRING_INDEX(site, "-", 1) = username
```

Change the schema so you don't need to do the `SUBSTRING_INDEX`!

Try to do some of what I *hinted* at, then come back with `SHOW CREATE TABLE` for each table.

Comment: Hi Rick, thanks for the response.
I have multiple different tables in two different databases, 'a' is not connected to anything in the query you gave me, did you mean to query the same table twice?
Thanks.

Comment: OK, what I provided is a shambles.  But see if you can `SELECT` from each table only once, doing all the `SUMs` and `COALESCEs` that are practical.  Then `JOIN` the tables together.

Comment: Issue is I need to do an internal calculation (second correlated subquery) I don't have a row for the results returned in that row. I am only using two tables, the "Finance" and "AllResults" here is a screenshot of the "SHOW CREATE TABLE"

https://screenshot.cool/MbDOy1X28RAwUZRGerYD
in my example i said it was "username" but it's actually an email. thanks again.

Comment: @Noy - Side issues:  InnoDB tables need `PRIMARY KEYs`.  Dates should use `DATE` datatype (usually).  Currency should use `DECIMAL`, not  `FLOAT`.

Comment: I see, I altered the table to change this, and a primary key is obviously not possible in this kind of table I'm using. Going back to the main issue, is there a way to do this without "cross joining" these two tables?

Comment: @Noy - When "cross joining", if there is a `WHERE` clause that relates then, it is as good as an `ON` clause.  (For clarity, `ON` should say how the tables relate; `WHERE` should be used for filtering.)